# Modify web.config on runtime

Tags: asp.net, web-config

If I modify an object on web.config that populates a combobox in a web application that is in a staging area or even production, do I need to restart the IIS or it detects that the web.config was changed?

Sorry for the silly question
Ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Changes to configuration settings in Web.config files indirectly cause
>   the application domain to restart. This behavior occurs by design.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ackhksh7.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

any change to the web.config will initiate a recycle of the application pool, you do not need to restart anything.